# Serialize int array into binary / base64 form to be used in VTK

Tags: .net, f#, binary, base64, vtk

I am writing my own writer for VTK XML files using F#. The VTK file needs a base64 encoding of binary data, together with a header as described [here](http://www.geophysik.uni-muenchen.de/intranet/it-service/applications/paraview/vtk-file-formats/).

> ... So the binary data has to be base64-encoded. Additionally, there is a header prepended to the data; it is a 32 bit integer containing the data length (in bytes). This header is encoded separately. So in pseudocode, the data output would look like this (always without spaces or line breaks!)

My code looks like:

```
let toBase64 (v: int []) =
  use ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
  let s = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
  s.Serialize(ms, v)
  let b = ms.ToArray()
  let len = System.BitConverter.GetBytes b.Length
  System.Convert.ToBase64String len + System.Convert.ToBase64String b
```

The result, however, is not correct. For the following input:

```
toBase64 [| 1; 2; 3; 4 |]
```

ParaView (written in C++) displays ranges -256 to 511 instead of 1 to 4. Do you see any obvious bug in my code?

**Edit**: My base64 encoded data looks like:

> LAAAAAABAAAA/////wEAAAAAAAAADwEAAAAEAAAACAEAAAACAAAAAwAAAAQAAAAL

**EDIT 2**: I enclose my solution which takes an array of float and convert it into Byte array, compress it using Ionic.Zip.dll ZLib and convert it into a base64 string. The function works fine with VTK XML file.

```
let toZlib (v: float []) =
  use msSinkCompressed = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
  let zOut = new ZlibStream(msSinkCompressed, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.Default, true)
  for i in v do 
    let bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes i
    zOut.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
  zOut.Flush()
  zOut.Close()
  let comprBytes = msSinkCompressed.ToArray()
  let header =
    let blocks = System.BitConverter.GetBytes 1
    let len = System.BitConverter.GetBytes (v.Length * 8)
    let comprLen = System.BitConverter.GetBytes comprBytes.Length
    Array.append(Array.append (Array.append blocks len) len) comprLen
  System.Convert.ToBase64String header + System.Convert.ToBase64String comprBytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the VTK format, but I would be very surprised if `BinaryFormatter` was the way to go - I think it generates some proprietary encoding of .NET types and it includes a lot of additional information (that the VTK format doesn't need, unless it is based on binary .NET serialization).

I think that writing the integer values directly to the stream would be a better idea. As I said, I don't know the format, but I'd expect that something like this would be closer to what you need:

```
let toBase64 (v: int []) = 
  use ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream() 
  for i in v do 
    let bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes i
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
  let b = ms.ToArray() 
  let len = System.BitConverter.GetBytes b.Length 
  System.Convert.ToBase64String len + System.Convert.ToBase64String b
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine! Are you familiar with zlib? I would like to take the data, zlib them and base64 them and save them into XML. Can I use GZipStream for that?

Answer (score 0):

Why would Paraview display 1 through 4? `BinaryFormatter` is a complex beast that includes *lots* of additional metadata about .NET types. If you can clarify how you want this encoded, it can perhaps help. For example, if your 1-4 are *bytes* you should be able to base-64 encode them directly. If they are to be treated as integers, you'd need to encode them to bytes first.

Ultimately, without a *detailed* encoding rule (including endianness etc) it is hard to give a definitive answer, but `BinaryFormatter` almost certainly isn't it.

I'm very familiar with custom binary encoding, and I'm happy to offer more help/guidance, but I really need more info in terms of what the protocol is *expecting*.

For example, **using C#** (sorry, my F#-foo is limited), and assuming little-endian fixed-length 32-bit integer encoding throughout:

```
static void Main() {
    string s = Encode(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
}
static string Encode(int[] data) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Length * 4];
    int offset = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < data.Length ; i++) {
        int value = data[i];
        buffer[offset++] = (byte)value;
        buffer[offset++] = (byte)(value >> 8);
        buffer[offset++] = (byte)(value >> 16);
        buffer[offset++] = (byte)(value >> 24);
    }
    byte[] header = new byte[4];
    int len = buffer.Length;
    header[0] = (byte)len;
    header[1] = (byte)(len >> 8);
    header[2] = (byte)(len >> 16);
    header[3] = (byte)(len >> 24);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(header) + Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}
```